# Spark on YARN failure to launch NodeManager and ResourceManager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Our issue: (we’re running yarn-client)

- This happens for both ./spark-shell

  ```
  scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).collect()
  ```

  and ./pyspark

  ```
  >>> sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4]).collect()
  ```
- The shell output from the basic jobs above outputs this error

  > WARN YarnClientClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
- The logs output this line in continuous succession: (the time_stamp and port_number change, but each job outputs this error

  > ERROR ExecutorLauncher: Failed to connect to driver at LOCALHOST:< port_number>, retrying ...
- We have SPARK_LOCAL_IP=LOCALHOST set in our spark-env.sh (everything else fails to even instantiate a sc in the REPL, examples: ip_address, HOSTNAME, and commenting it out entirely)

Our Setup:

- Using almost all default YARN settings in the spark-defaults.conf and spark-env.sh
- This is robust hardware:

  - 128 GB per node,
  - 16 cores,
  - 2 TB physical memory
- The Spark master is on its own node, as are the ResourceManager, and the NodeManager (with about 5 data nodes)

Errors:
(in REPL)

> WARN YarnClientClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory

(in YARN logs)

> 15/09/12 13:03:00 INFO ExecutorLauncher: Waiting for Spark driver to be reachable.
>   15/09/12 13:03:00 ERROR ExecutorLauncher: Failed to connect to driver at LOCALHOST:45790, retrying ...

Comment: Can you share the spark-submit command being used to launch this?

Answer (score 0):

The last error log is pretty neat: executors are trying to contact the driver on localhost:45790, but it is not listening there.

What you want to do is update the `spark.driver.host` and `spark.driver.port` in the `/path/to/spark/conf/spark-default.conf` file, to something your executor will be able to contact.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to your local host IP (the one other than the loopback IP)

So if your ip is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And then make sure that the driver is actually running